# Exclude a MAC address from the Hyper-V address pool

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v

I have a Hyper-V environment on Windows Server 2012 Datacenter. One of the Virtual Machine (VM) has a License Server. One of the license was generated due to the Mac address that the VM had at that moment. My VMs take the MAC addresses dynamically from the Hyper-V pool. I will change the Mac address configuration in only that VM from dynamic to static MAC address. I will put the MAC address that the VM had at that moment (the license file gives me the MAC at that moment) but I would like to exclude that MAC address from the Hyper-V MAC address pool to avoid conflicts. How can I exclude an specific MAC address from the Hyper-V pool?

Comment: What you ought to do is to "rehome" your license to the static MAC address. That might necessitate a call to the vendor for that particular piece of software.

Comment: Unfortunately, the vendor attache the license to a MAC address.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you ought to speak to the vendor about releasing the license from the dynamic MAC address and applying it to the static MAC address. I have to think that in today's virtualized world that they've dealt with this before.

Comment: Definitely, I will speak to the vendor to see if they can release a dynamic MAC address version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easier to just change the MAC address range (pool) to something else that doesn't include the address in question. Microsoft has set aside  00-15-5D-* for hyper-V so change a part past that. So if the pool was:

[image]

you would change something in the -01-F7- part of the minimum and maximum.

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you for your answer. I was thinking on that too. I think it will be a good solution.